# Wrong hyperref by using glossaries for symbols

Tags: hyperref, symbols, glossaries

When I use the `glossaries` package for my symbols, the `hyperref` of the symbols in the text didn't work. Every ref goes to the first page of my document.

> How can I solve it, that the hyperref is linked to the page of my symbols?

> *Another little question*: Can I sort the symbols in alphabetic order? Thank you all.

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[
ngerman,
11pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[ 
hidelinks,
breaklinks
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% Glossaries
\usepackage[
automake,       
nonumberlist,       
acronym,            
toc,            
]{glossaries}


%% Symbolverzeichnis 
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis} 
\makeglossaries 
\newif\ifsubhead 
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\glssetnoexpandfield{useri}

\newglossarystyle{mysymbols}{ 
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}% 
    {\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}csp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}@{}}}
        {\end{longtable}}% 
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{} 
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{% 
        \glsentryitem{##1}% 
        \ifglshassymbol{##1}{ 
            \global\subheadfalse 
            \glossentrysymbol{##1}% 
        }{% 
            \global\subheadtrue 
            \glstarget{##1}{% 
                \rule{0pt}{2pc} 
                \makebox[0pt][l]{\glossentryname{##1}} 
                \hphantom{\textbf{Symbol}} 
            } 
        } & 
        \glsentryuseri{##1} & 
        \glossentrydesc{##1} 
        \glspostdescription & ##2 
        \ifsubhead 
        \tabularnewline[1pc] 
        \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Beschreibung\tabularnewline[1pc] 
        \else 
        \tabularnewline 
        \fi 
    }% 
    \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{ 
        \glossentry{##2}{##3} 
    }% 
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\relax} 
} 

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 

\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{name={\textbf{\large Lateinische Buchstaben}},description={}} 
\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{name={\textbf{\large Griechische Buchstaben}},description={}} 

\newglossaryentry{symb:c}{ 
    name=Lichtgeschwindigkeit, 
    description={Lichtgeschwindigkeit}, 
    symbol={$c$}, 
    type=symbols, 
    user1={\meter\per\second}, 
    parent=romanletter 
}

\newglossaryentry{symb:freq}{ 
    name=Frequenz, 
    description={Frequenz}, 
    symbol={$f$}, 
    type=symbols, 
    user1={\per\second}, 
    parent=romanletter 
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:eta}{ 
    name=Wirkungsgrad, 
    description={Wirkungsgrad}, 
    symbol={$\eta$}, 
    type=symbols, 
    user1={-}, 
    parent=greekletter 
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[5]
    \newpage
    \printglossary[title=Symbolverzeichnis,type=symbols,style=mysymbols] \newpage
    \gls{symb:c} and \gls{symb:eta} and \gls{symb:freq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not at pc, but do remember that hyperref should be one of the last packages loaded as it has to adapt to a lot of other packages

Comment: When i load it after glossaries, the hyperref doesn't exist. Loading it before, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the target command here in your style definition

```
 \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}%
        \ifglshassymbol{##1}{
            \global\subheadfalse
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}% <-------------
        }{%
```